# Finding nearest neighbors between two tables with point locations in SpatiaLite?

Tags: sql, spatialite, nearest-neighbor

I have started playing with SpatiaLite today and already stumbled upon a problem.

For each point location stored in tableOne I would like to select one, nearest (linear distance) point from tableTwo.

So far I came up with a clumsy solution that utilizes VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW testview AS 
SELECT 
A.id , 
B.myValue, 
Distance(A.Geometry, B.Geometry) AS distance
FROM tableOne AS A, tableTwo AS B
WHERE distance < 10000
ORDER BY A.Id, distance;
```

And then:

```
SELECT * FROM testview
WHERE distance = (SELECT MIN(distance) FROM testview AS t WHERE t.id = testview.id)
```

seems to do the job.

Two questions:

Is there a way to perform such query without creating a VIEW?

Is there any other way to optimize this query for better performance? 
In a real world scenario tableOne will have hundreds-couple thousands records, and tableTwo - 1.3 million.

Comment: I can give you an approach that is several orders of magnitude faster, but it would require you to use postgresql 9 knngist index instead of spatialite...

Comment: actually faster than GRASS, ArcGIS, QGIS, SQLServer and pretty much any other spatial db/Desktop GIS (have not tried Oracle nearest neighbour functionality though).Just let me know if it is an option.

Comment: @Ragi: I'm aware that PostGIS would be much more efficient way to work with such problem. However the ultimate goal of this exercise would be to make small portable app and in this case SpatiaLite is a winner.

Comment: What's your development platform for your portable app?

Comment: @Allan: Working on both: Windows Server 2008 & Ubuntu at the moment.

Comment: @Radek the pure knngist solution is also faster than anything currently on PostGIS. Is as portable as postgres... so you are right that mobile would not be included. You would need to modify spatialite itself in a very non-trivial way to achieve something remotely similar.

Comment: @radek, I'd hate to assume that you may be using Python for a portable app, but if you are, I'd consider looking at the Rtree package for Python. You can spatially index objects and persist them to disk, as well as perform k-nearest neighbor searches for said Python objects. Rtree is a Python wrapper for libspatialindex (http://libspatialindex.github.com). If you might consider using Rtree or even libspatialindex for persisting data instead of SpatialLite, let me know if your interested. I've been able to effectively use it lately and I'm quite impressed.

Comment: @Ragi: Thanks. KNNGiST looks very impressive indeed. But probably beyond my skills level at the moment :/

Comment: @Allan: Seems like Python will be my next stop if SpatiaLite won't cope on its own. Thanks for pointers to libspatialindex - will have a look. I'll either edit this question to include Python or ask a new one. So if you can share some more pointers/examples - please do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just tested this SQL and it works:

```
SELECT g1.OGC_FID As id1, g2.OGC_FID As id2, MIN(ST_Distance(g1.GEOMETRY,g2.GEOMETRY)) AS DIST
FROM table_01 As g1, table_02 As g2   
WHERE g1.OGC_FID <> g2.OGC_FID
AND ST_Contains(ST_Expand(g1.geometry,50),g2.geometry)
GROUP BY id1
ORDER BY id1
```

As you can read [here](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/knn.html) "The naive way to carry out a nearest neighbour query is to order the candidate table by distance from the query geometry, and then take the record with the smallest distance".

Best regards,

Andrea

Comment: I am trying to use this query but I am getting unexpected results - I am getting a resulting table but with IDs for lines I can see are not the nearest neighbor. I am trying to find the closest line in a multiline string layer to each point in another layer. I am new with spatiaLite. Any suggestions? Also, I ultimately want to run this on 1 million+ points

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand the purpose of this statement: WHERE g1.OGC_FID <> g2.OGC_FID

Comment: Also, in my result I am getting null distance. I have played around with this line: AND ST_Contains(ST_Expand(g1.geometry,50),g2.geometry) as well as removed it and still get no distance values, even though I am getting an ID

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to compute the distances between all the point combinations, you can use a spatial index on one of the table :

```sql
SELECT 
  A.id , 
  B.myValue, 
  MIN(Distance(A.Geometry, B.Geometry)) AS distance
FROM tableOne AS A, tableTwo AS B
WHERE A.ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM SpatialIndex WHERE
    f_table_name = 'A' 
    AND search_frame = BuildCircleMbr(ST_X(B.Geometry), ST_Y(B.Geometry), 10000))
GROUP BY A.id, B.myValue
```

Comment: I've tried to use the solution you posted as I need to use a spatial index, but it returns no values? for the line `f_table_name = 'A'`, do I need to replace 'A' with the actual table name (table one)? I've tried either way and it still doesn't return anything, why might this be

Comment: You are right `f_table_name = 'A'` should be  `f_table_name = 'tableOne'`. Note that this request assumes spatialite > 4.x (`SpatialIndex` virtual table is used). Did you try to adjust the `search_frame` for your use case ? In the example above, points are assumed to be at a maximum distance of 10000 meters.

Comment: I did play around with the search frame value, I assume that means within 10000 meters which should work for me. I don't actually know which version of spatialite, I created the database through qgis and am using the gui in qgis. Let me see if i can figure that out

Comment: It is version 4.1.1 with sqlite version 3.7.17, so it should work then? I wonder what is wrong I will test it some more

Answer (score 4):

Since version 4.4.0 SpatiaLite supports a KNN virtual table index for nearest neighbor problems. Here is a query the finds the nearest line in a linestring table to each point in a point table.

```
SELECT k.* FROM knn k, points p
WHERE f_table_name = 'linestrings' 
AND ref_geometry = p.geometry
AND max_items = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your query like this.

```
SELECT 
   A.id , 
   B.myValue, 
   MIN(Distance(A.Geometry, B.Geometry)) AS distance
FROM tableOne AS A, tableTwo AS B
GROUP BY A.id, B.myValue
```

For a more generic solution, it might be worth trying to convert this PostGIS Nearest Neighbor function: http://blog.mackerron.com/2011/03/postgis-nearest-neighbour/

Comment: unfortunately the code results in: `SQL error: "misuse of aggregate: MIN()"`

Comment: As of PostGIS there are also some [examples](http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor_generic) on BostonGIS website, but so far I wasn't successful in translating them into SpatiaLite :/