# Spatialite KNN - No results

Tags: python, spatialite, sqlite, knn

**SOLVED**: f_table_name was not working as no spatialindex was created/defined using just the tutorial for VirtualKNN - Solution: Run the query

```
SELECT CREATESPATIALINDEX('tablename','geom_col')
```

**Original Problem**

First time using spatialite - followed a tutorial to set-up my database and ran a basic distance function to get the nearest objectid - works great but I have A LOT of points so I decided to use the virtualKNN - ran it on the same point to test but KNN returns nothing - tried without the PointFromText as well but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

My end goal is to run a KNN from another bunch of points from another table but this is throwing up a blank table as well.

[image]

Looks like something wrong with the way i am calling f_table_name?

I have a table called LION but i guess it is not able to see that?

I get a blank result when i call anything in the between the '' that doesn't exist so f_table_name is having trouble reading my table?

[image]

Edit - Added code

This is the distance function that works

```
query='''
Select OBJECTID, Distance(PointFromText('POINT(-73.9215944000000036 40.8278258999999935)'),wkb_geometry) as distance
,wkb_geometry
FROM LION
Order by distance
'''

test=pd.read_sql_query(query,db)
test[~test['distance'].isnull()]
```

This is the knn query that returns a null table because it can't read f_table_name

```
query='''
Select * FROM knn
WHERE f_table_name = 'LION' 
AND ref_geometry = MakePoint(-73.9215944000000036, 40.8278258999999935);
'''

test=pd.read_sql_query(query,db)
test.head(100)
```

Comment: Hi @KadirŞahbaz - given you don't have access to my DB i thought the code was less relevant and i was really trying to highlight the output that works for distance functions but not the KNN. 

The code is basically from the tutorials adapted from the tutorial below - https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=KNN

I guess the point was trying to make was that f_table_name doesn't seem to work (i.e its calling blanks info even when the table exists

Comment: If you make it impossible for folks to cut/paste your code, you run the risk that they won't bother to try.

Comment: @Vince sure understand. Added the code for the 2 queries - the distance that works and the knn that fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should follow the tutorial https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=KNN and function reference manual http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html with the airport data and make sure that you have a working system before switching to your own data.

You commands seem to be mostly OK but this part in one of your tests  is wrong:

```
ref_geometry=PointFromText(MakePoint...
```

MakePoint functions returns a geometry object, and passing that to PointFromText returns `NULL`. Therefore no selected lines from KNN is an expected result. Use either `MakePoint` or `PointFromText` with correct syntax and your first query should return results. However, I see that you have used just MakePoint inother case.

You do not need to include `f_geometry_column` if your table does not have many geometry fields. That would simplify the SQL a bit.

Comment: Thanks! I actually did follow the tutorial - then i tried other things to troubleshoot. 

Thought it was having trouble finding the f_geometry_column so i added it (docs say it is not required). Thought maybe it was unable to read my point (so i messed with the point function a bit)

Turns out the f_table_name is not reading my table (even tho its there and is a geospatial table) but can't figure out why or how to fix. I can put anything after the = and it will return a blank which suggest that when i put my actual table its not even reading that either.

Comment: How did you create your own database? Does the test database https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/knn/airports.7z work in your environment?

Comment: The test data base works in my environment - just ran it and the KNN runs fine. 

I created my db using sqlite3 in python:
1. Upload without geoms to_sql
2. AddGeometryColumn after InitSpatialMetaData
3. Convert geoms to WKB then Update/Set/Where on id to update the table with the geoms

Comment: What if you `DROP TABLE knn` and then `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE knn USING VirtualKNN();`  for creating it again?

Comment: I tried that but still doesn't work

However, I  took a look at the files in the airport.sqlite and my db and noticed that in the example there is a idx_airports_geom table that creates a virtual table using rtree that I don't have in mine for my tables (along with idx_airports_geom_node, _parent _rowid). From what i understand the KNN runs off RTree so it seems like i need this table?

Comment: For sure KNN needs a spatial index. It should have been documented better. Create one with CreateSpatialIndex http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html and try again.

Comment: Legend! This works now - Thanks for the help and walking me thru it!

Comment: Sorry - got a bit too excited there - it works for querying the ref_geometry = MakePoint(Lat,Lon) but fails when I run this:


`query='''
Select k.* 
FROM knn k, speedcam p
WHERE f_table_name = 'LION'
AND ref_geometry = p.wkb_geometry
'''

test=pd.read_sql_query(query,spatcon)
test.head(100)`


Where speedcam is another Spatial table with points in wkb_geometry with Spatial index declared following the pattern [link] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155725/using-nearest-neighbor-query-in-spatialite?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I think it was me, was using `ST_GeomFromText` to create points and the points weren't getting created - on a related note how long is it expected to run for 7.3mn points knn against 230k lines?

Comment: Query with one reference geometry against 4 million polygons takes about 0.4 seconds for me.  Multiply that. But I would consider if your query makes sense as it stands now. You seem to use every single geometry in the speedcam table as reference geometry. Perhaps you would like to include an ID of the speedcam into the result as well.

Comment: Good point - in addition, while there are 7.3mn records, they overlap on 1687 unique points - so i could essentially run it on a much smaller table

Comment: So my query(the one above) on 1700 points took 14mins but on second point set of 9300 points took just over 5hrs - both against the same line data base with spatial index on both set of geoms - I thought it should scale linearly any idea why it might be doing this? I’ve one more 20k point set to run…